# Link between beacon chain slot and execution chain block

Tags: blocks, beacon-chain, slots

I have researched info about this **topic** and I seem to find no answer. If it already has been asked please kindly provide the link for it.

I would like to know the link between **slot** and **block**.

From what I have read we are now on capella upgrade. The content of the blocs from beacon API has always *eth1_data*, but since the bellatrix upgrade there is an *execution_payload*.

My confusion comes when I see that both provide a *blockHash* property which they differ.

My question is: Which one links to the execution layer block? *eth1_data* or *execution_payload* ?